# Android file path

Tags: android, performance

i wanted to add file with specific path like that to view it as in image .. worked fine

```
File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DSC_0008.JPG");

    if (imgFile.exists()) {

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

**BUT** 
that is not where i find my photo .. if i tried opening it manually and not from the studio

any idea how this work .. and how do i know the path that should i use to get any photo on my android

Comment: Please do not hard-code that fixed address in your code, query the media store instead.

Comment: how should i do that ?

Comment: You can add file chooser .... to get path of your desire file ..

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a hardcoded path demonstrating this problem. The image is loaded so it's a valid path. `i tried opening it manually `. You should explain what you really did. Which file explorer app did you use? A normal file explorer app should show it.

Answer (score 1):

The "/storage/emulated/0/" folder does not really exist.

It's what might be called a "symbolic link", or, in simpler terms, a reference to where the real data is stored. You'll need to find the actual physical location on your device where it is stored.

Since it's in /storage/emulated/0/DSC_0008.JPG, it's probably located in /Internal Storage/DSC_0008.JPG/. Please note that that this folder probably only contains "DSC_0008.JPG", which are very small versions of the real files.

It's possible your real files are gone forever if your SD card is irrecoverable.

As Hiren stated, you'll need a file explorer to see your directory. If you're rooted I highly suggest root explorer, otherwise ES File Explorer is a good choice.

### You can user file chooser for get image path

```
    private void chooserImage(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(intent, 1888);
    }
```

Then override a method called `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode ==  getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode==1888){
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    String path = imageUri.getPath().toString();
    File imgFile = new File(new URI(path));
    //Then Here user your code

   if (imgFile.exists()) {

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
   }

  }
  }
```

### Just Call on any event `chooserImage();` to choose file and show as ImageView

You need one more step: set permission to read SD card. Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `The "/storage/emulated/0/" folder does not really exist. `. Does not matter. With a file explorer app you can go there. And it has nothing to do with rooting.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the filename, DSC_0008.JPG, I'm assuming it was made with the Camera app. If that's the case your file should be in /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/

Comment: yeah i know that .. but in other apps's photo i don't

Comment: static hard coded paths will not work.. Since there are lots of devices with different name structure. So this way is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**File imgFile = getOutputFile("myfileName", "imagesSubFolder");**

```
public static File getOutputFile(String fileName, String subFolderName) {

    File mediaStorageDir;

    if (subFolderName == null) {
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), Path.PHOTO_DIRECTORY);
    } else {
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), Path.PHOTO_DIRECTORY + File.separator + subFolderName);
    }

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {

        try {

            if (subFolderName != null) {
                File noMediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir, ".nomedia");
                noMediaFile.createNewFile();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
}
```

good luck